# Why aluminium for load cells?

Tags: load-cell

I am currently working with load cells for weighing small masses. Almost all of them, as far as I have looked, have been made from aluminium. Given that repeatability is critical, why aluminium and not (say) spring steel or a stiffer material?

[I know that this may well be flagged for close as off topic, but would still appreciate any info.]

Comment: Is that why is aluminium used on the load cell arm, or why the sensor itself is made of aluminium? If you're asking about the structure that moves, aluminium is nice springy material, it deflects more and goes back to its original shape better than steel does (I@m sure someone will be able to get the figures)

Answer (score 2):

I think it has to do with price; aluminium alloys are cheaper and easier to machine than (stainless) steel. The aluminium alloys used today are as good or better at returning to their original position as steel is, so no problem there.

Comment: to support that answer, we can assume it's not pure aluminium but a alloy with other materials. there are many different sorts of aluminium, and it can be quite hard and stiff.

Comment: No, it's always an alloy; 2XXX series alloys (duralumin in older documents) seem to be the most popular for load cells. Up to 5% copper in those, don't know about the other metals in it. Edited the answer, thanks.

Comment: I am no specialist in metals (but I can ask the mechanical engineers in my team if needed :-)) - As far as I know copper makes the aluminium a bit harder and improves machinability in terms of how chips are produced...